# Send API notification OneSignal for multiple users

Tags: onesignal

I'm try send a API Notification by OneSignal to API REST, when I send for a unique user it's work right, but when have to more than one user in Json, the notification is sent for unique user yet.

```
My JSON (listOnesignal):[{"key":"user","relation":"=","value":"YAlBcuwiOJ"},{"key":"user","relation":"=","value":"MSoVMRxzbh"}]    

var jsonBody = { 
                  app_id: "appid", 
                  android_background_data: true,
                  tags: listOneSignal,
                  data: {anything}
    };
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add an `OR` operator between each entry as `AND` is used by default.

```
[{"key":"user","relation":"=","value":"YAlBcuwiOJ"},
 {"operator": "OR"},
 {"key":"user","relation":"=","value":"MSoVMRxzbh"}]
```

Note that there is a limit of 200 entries (including `OR`'s) on the `tags` field per REST API call. You can use `include_player_ids` instead if you need to target more devices at a time as you can send up to 2,000.

See the OneSignal [create notification REST API](https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference#create-notification) documentation page for more details.

Comment: But I need send for the two or more users in the same time, this will work?

Comment: Yes, in the above example both user "YAlBcuwiOJ" and "MSoVMRxzbh" will get the same notification.

Comment: Thanks, @jkasten. I'm using the CSharp SDK and there's almost no documentation for it. Your example led me in the right direction and I found how to do the same thing with C#. I've added that answer in case it's useful for someone looking for the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

In case someone is using the OneSignal CSharp SDK, this is how you can do the same thing (although this example uses tags instead of player ids):

```
IList<INotificationFilter> filters = new List<INotificationFilter>();

foreach (var tag in tagList)
{
    var filter = new NotificationFilterField
    {
        Field = NotificationFilterFieldTypeEnum.Tag,
        Key = "tag_id",
        Value = tag,
        Relation = "="
    };

    if (filters.Count > 0)
        filters.Add(new NotificationFilterOperator { Operator = "OR" });

    filters.Add(filter);
}

var client = new OneSignalClient("...");

var options = new NotificationCreateOptions
{
    AppId = new Guid("..."),
    Filters = filters
};

options.Contents.Add(...);
client.Notifications.Create(options);
```